# If a separate thread(which uses time.sleep() inside) is made manually in a multi threaded python application, will that affect the performance?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

```py
import threading
import time

def scheduler():
    periodic_action() # requires distributed locking and it's enough if it only runs ONCE every 1 hour
    time.sleep(3600) # 1 hour
    threading.Thread(target=scheduler, daemon=True).start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    threading.Thread(target=scheduler, daemon=True).start()
```

This code runs in a multithreaded environment with 5 threads (gunicorn gthread). And periodic_action() will do its job, even if it runs only once (that is why I want only one thread to run it). I am not sure is this a good way of scheduling? Will one thread will be *always* reserved for this scheduling task? and we will be having effectively 4 threads? How does GIL perform for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `time.sleep()` inside a thread is a very efficient way of having a thread delay before doing something else. You can have a large number of threads all doing this and it will still be very efficient.

(However, the `periodic_action()` will be subject to the GIL, especially if several threads wake up at the same time).

Additionally, you won't need the `scheduler()` function start another thread, it may as well be like this:

```py
def scheduler():
    while True:
        periodic_action()
        time.sleep(3600) # 1 hour
```